# What character to use for entry to appear always last?

Tags: windows

I have this panel on the Win 7 taskbar, "Desktop" that shows me contents of my desktop on  click.

It looks like [Desktop >>], and if you want to have one:

- right click your taskbar
- choose Toolbars
- check Desktop.

**The main part**

So I want one of the names to appear always last in the drop-down, and preferably not to have a letter as a first character, as this is just ugly.

**_** and **{** usually appear last, but this still is ugly.

Anyone tried this at home?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086375/what-character-to-use-to-put-an-item-at-the-end-of-an-alphabetic-list